# How to get the route and its params in canActivate and canActivateChild

Tags: angular

Im using angular 11 and each routing and reloading i m using authguard to check the route is access or not.

Now i have issue which route has params,

/fee-collection/reports/view/:school_id/:year_id/:date_range/:mode

i have this as a child route and in menu file

```
 {
    id: "fee-collection",
    title: "Fees",
    type: "collapsable",
    icon: "heroicons_outline:currency-rupee",
    children: [
      {
        id: "View-reports_4",
        title: "View Fee Reports",
        type: "basic",
        icon: "heroicons_outline:ticket",
        link: `/fee-collection/reports/view/:school_id/:year_id/:date_range/:mode`,
        externalLink: true,
        hidden: (title: FuseNavigationItem) => true,
      }
}
```

In routing.ts file

```
{
    path: "",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    component: LayoutComponent,
    resolve: {
      initialData: InitialDataResolver,
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("app/modules/fee-collection/fee-collection.module").then(
            (m) => m.FeeCollectionModule
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
```

In authguard file

```
     /**
   * Can activate
   *
   * @param route
   * @param state
   */
  
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    // console.log(this._authService.isLoggedIn);
    console.log(route, "queryParams")
    this.params = route.paramMap.getAll(''); 
    console.log(state, "state")
    this._activatedroute.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params,"activated routes")
    })
    
    const redirectUrl = state.url === "/sign-out" ? "/" : state.url;
    return this._check(redirectUrl);
  }
```

im not able to get the params in canactivate while reloading the component, but when i navigate from one component to this component im able to get the params in canactivatechild

How to check the route is equal or not
because in menu file /fee-collection/reports/view/:school_id/:year_id/:date_range/:mode and in authguard i get the /fee-collection/reports/view/5/6/3/2

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet where you access the route parameters?

Comment: Can you try executing this code and see what it logs to the console?

route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params, "activated routes");
});

Comment: TypeError: route.params.subscribe is not a function error @Chellappanவ